# Can we have Multiple Admin Routing in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I want multiple admin routing..

One for Admin another for CLients.. is this possible. if not whats the best way to get around to this ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing). In Cake 1.2 it's [a bit different](http://book.cakephp.org/view/544/Prefix-Routing), but still usable.

There is [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152252/routing-admin-true-vs-prefix-admin-in-cakephp) on related questions here on SO :)