# cakephp link not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in php and cakephp. Just trying to make simple navigation menu.

```
<li><?php
      //pr($this->Html-);
      echo $this->Html->link('Entertainment', array(
          'controller' => 'UpcommingEntertainments',
          'action' => 'index'
      ));
      ?></li>
```

its works fine if I am at www.example.com. The problem is if I am at /admin/* and i click this link, it takes me to  www.example.com/admin/Entertainment, I want to go to www.wxample.com/Entertainment.
What should be my link code?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Entertainment', array(
      'controller' => 'UpcommingEntertainments',
      'action' => 'index',
      'admin' => false, // thats what you need
      'plugin' => false, // could be helpful if you plan using plugins
  ));
```

I included the plugin parameter, because you could encounter the same issue, if you use plugins.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><?php
      //pr($this->Html-);
      echo $this->Html->link('Entertainment', array(
          'admin' => false, // add this
          'controller' => 'UpcommingEntertainments',
          'action' => 'index'
      ));
      ?></li>
```

There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152252/routing-admin-true-vs-prefix-admin-in-cakephp) offering a bit more indepth explanation.