# Cakephp: Admin panel Integration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have my application running in cakephp with Front login authentication with the "LADP" AD(Active Directory). I have integrated the admin Panel By "Routing Prefix to Admin". So that I have my admin actions in the same controller as of front actions. Like `UsersController` having actions `login()`, `logout()`, `admin_login()`, `admin_logout()`. And `AdminContoller` having

```
public function index() {

    $username = $this->Session->read('Admin.username');
    if (empty($username)) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
    } else {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true));
    }
}
public function admin_dashboard() {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->loadModel('Group');
    $this->loadModel('News');
    $username = $this->Session->read('Admin.username');
    $group_id = $this->Session->read('Admin.group_id');

    if (empty($username) and ( $group_id = 1)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to view this Page!!'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-error'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
    }

    $users = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.group_id !=' => 1)));
    $groups = $this->Group->find('count');
    $news = $this->News->find('count', array('conditions' => array('News.expiry_date >= NOW()')));
    $this->set(compact('users', 'groups', 'news'));
}
```

And having `AppController` as below

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Paginator','Acl.AclHtml');
    public $components = array('Acl', 'Session',
        'Auth' => array(

            'authError' => 'You are not authorized to access that location.',
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
            'controllers' => array('users')
        ));

    public function beforeFilter() {
        // LDAP
        $server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $ldapIp = ClassRegistry::init('LdapIp');
        $ldapIpCount = $ldapIp->find('count', array('conditions' => array('ldap_ip' => $server_ip)));
        if ($ldapIpCount >= 1) {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Ldap');
        } else {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');
        }

        $this->Auth->allow();

        if (!$this->Auth->isAllow($this)) {
            $this->set(array(
                'message' => array(
                    'text' => __('un aunthaticated request'),
                    'type' => 'error',
                    'status' => "401"
                ),
                '_serialize' => array('message')
            ));
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I redirect Admin to `admin/admin_dashboard` if he is logged in but redirect him to `users/admin_login` if he is not, without having check into every controllers action? Can we check somewhere in `beforeFilter()` of `AppController`?

Please provide any suggestion with code to achieve this. I will integrate **"alaxos ACL plugin 2.0"** after this so please suggest me the code by keeping this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I used prefix 'admin' [if($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin')] for my project, in your case, change to controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    ....

    //Configure AuthComponent
    if($this->params['controller'] == 'admin') {
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'admin_login',
        );
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'admin_login',
        );
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
            'controller' => 'admin',
            'action' => 'dashboard',
        );
    }
    ....
}
```

I think you should use prefix 'admin'.

More info: [Admin Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152252/routing-admin-true-vs-prefix-admin-in-cakephp)

Comment: Can you explain in detail code here and also I need to implement ACL for admin/acl in My application (used alaxos ACL Plugin).

Comment: loginAction, logoutRedirect & loginRedirect is defined at [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html). It's fit to your case, when you need redirect someone that access to AdminController.

Comment: I have put this Auth code in AppController->beforefilter function

Comment: if(isset($this->request->prefix) && ($this->request->prefix == 'admin')){
            AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Admin';
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'admin','action'=>'dashboard');
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
            $this->Auth->allow(array('admin_dashboard'));
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User')
            );
        }

Comment: It will redirect to dashboard after login but when goto other links at admin it will redirect again to "users/admin_login".

Comment: $this->Auth->allow(array('admin_dashboard'));  => You only allowed this action.

Comment: If I do this way $this->Auth->allow(); then it will get direct access to the internal pages.....then all the pages gets access without having session..

Comment: You shouldn't add that line, just remove that :). Because you use ACL component, so don't need to use `Auth->allow()`. And don't forget to add `public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));` in User model. [Setup Simple ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html). Normaly, AuthComponent included Authenticate and Authorise [control access in controller]. If you use ACL, Auth now is Authenticate, and ACL is Authorize[control access in database].

Comment: Removed Allow now, But Every time i used to login it will flash a msg "Login sussesfull!" but doesn't redirecting to dashboard .....I think session isn't creating here is the code for

Comment: function admin_login() { $this->layout = 'admin_login'; if ($this->request->is('post')) { $username = $this-

>request->data['User']['username']; $password = $this->request->data['User']['password']; $password = 

Security::hash($password, null, true); $logged_in = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array

('User.username' => $username, 'User.password' => $password, 'User.role' => 'Admin', 'User.active' => 1))); if 

($logged_in >= 1) { $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login successful!'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-

success'));

Comment: $users = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $username, 

'User.password' => $password, 'User.role' => 'Admin', 'User.active' => 1))); $this->Session->write('Admin.id', 

$users['User']['id']); $this->Session->write('Admin.username', $users['User']['username']); $this->Session->write

('Admin.group_id', $users['User']['group_id']); $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 

'dashboard', 'admin' => true)); } else { Username or password is incorrect}}}

Comment: Setup for AuthComponent is just a define, you should do that and reuse in another controller. Ex: If user login is successful:  `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`

Comment: I uses like this and doesn't work out also                                         public function admin_login() {
        $this->layout = 'admin_login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username and password, try again'));
            }                                                                                                                          }
    }